# Angularjs ng-model complex link between two select tags

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I have a json containing a list of vehicle trends and there corresponding models.

```
var availables = {
  "trends": [
    {"label": "ALFA ROMEO"}
  ],
  "models": {
    "ALFA ROMEO": [
      {"label": "159"},
      {"label": "4C"},
      {"label": "AR8C SPIDER"},
      {"label": "BRERA"},
      {"label": "GIULIETTA"},
      {"label": "MITO"},
      {"label": "SPIDER"}]
  }
}
```

I want to display them in two `select`. The first select must condition the second one. I did like this and it works fine. When I select a trend, the other `select` only shows me the good models.

```
<label class="item item-input item-select">
  <span class="input-label">Véhicule</span>
  <select ng-model="vehicle.trend" ng-options="trend.label for trend in trends_availables.trends">
    <option ng-disabled="true" ng-selected="true" value="">{{"select_trend" | translate}}</option>
  </select>
</label>

<label class="item item-input item-select">
  <span class="input-label">Modèle</span>
  <select ng-model="vehicle.model" ng-options="model.label for model in trends_availables.models[vehicle.trend.label]">
    <option ng-disabled="true" ng-selected="true" value="">{{"select_model" | translate}}</option>
  </select>
</label>
```

Here comes my problem. when I have a already created `vehicle`, the `selects` does not show the good trend and model. As `vehicle.trend` is an object, I can understand the `ng-model` fails to get the `label` attribute.

How could I make the two `select` working in dependency and the trend/model showing the good labels ?

When I get a `vehicle` like this one `$scope.vehicle = {"trend": {"label": "ALFA ROMEO"}, "model": {"label": "159"}};` I want the selects to show the good informations.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on your issue? I know it is working, but your problem is not clear. I've created a CodePen to help figure out a solution once I know what the problem is.

[CodePen Demo](http://codepen.io/Manbearpixel/pen/WwLKBa)

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: So to clarify, you want to now **remove** all the other select options from the select input that do **not** match what you have already selected

Comment: I want when my vehicle object is `{"trend": {"label": "ALFA ROMEO"}, "model": {"label": "159"}};` that the select option of the trend is selected on ALFA ROMEO and the model one selected on 159. Like this I can see what the vehicle is and change the trend or the model.

Comment: But that is exactly what is happening is it not? When you choose an option from a select input element, that select input then is set to the chosen option.

Comment: The link between the first select and the second works, but when the vehicle is defined, the select tags do not show the good attributes value. I have forked your [codepen](http://codepen.io/Al1_andre/pen/JXwmGv). Vehicle is defined, but it only shows `select_trend`

Answer (score 1):

It might help if you can elaborate a little more, but this codepen may demonstrate what you need: http://codepen.io/Findiglay/pen/mPajZB?editors=1010

I've changed the select menus slighty, as follows:

```
 <label class="item item-input item-select">
    <span class="input-label">Véhicule</span>
    <select ng-model="vehicle.trend" ng-options="trend.label for trend in availables.trends", ng-change="updateModels()">
      <option value=""> -- Select a Trend -- </option>
    </select>
  </label>

  <label class="item item-input item-select">
    <span class="input-label">Modèle</span>
    <select ng-model="vehicle.model" ng-options="model.label for model in filteredModels">
    </select>
  </label>
```

Let me know if this does not solve the problem exactly and I can help further.

Edit: I've updated the answer to automatically select the available vehicles for the selected model. Does this now address the issue you are describing?

> When you choose an option from a select input element, that select
>   input then is set to the chosen option

I've made updates to the html above and added the following function to be fired with ng-change:

```
 /** Update Available Models when a trend is selected **/
  $scope.updateModels = function() {
    if ($scope.vehicle.trend && availables.models[$scope.vehicle.trend.label]) {
     $scope.filteredModels = availables.models[$scope.vehicle.trend.label]; 
    } else {
     $scope.filteredModels = [{
       label: '-- Select a Model --'
     }];
    }
    $scope.vehicle.model = $scope.filteredModels[0];
  };
```

Check the codepen! Hope this helps.

Comment: Does this address the problem?

Comment: No, but I think I fail explaining my problem because you give me the opposite of what I need. What I need is when the `vehicle` model is set (by ajax) that the `select` tags show the good labels for the trend and the model.